# How to display an <img> from a variable in TWIG

Tags: php, html, symfony, twig

I want to create a chat system and I want to integrate the possibility to add an emoji. So, I save in my database the message content and an `<img>` for each emoji the user adds. The problem is that when I want to display the emoji image it doesn't shows as a image, but as a text.

For example, if I have the following message:

```
TestMessage
```

I save in database as

```
TestMessage<img alt="" class="emojioneemoji" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/emojione/assets/3.1/png/32/1f601.png"><img alt="" class="emojioneemoji" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/emojione/assets/3.1/png/32/1f601.png">
```

And when I try to display the message in TWIG I get the same as in database, the `<img>` isn't considerated a tag. This is how I tried to display the message, but none of these worked:

```
{{ message.content}}

{{ message.content| raw}}

{{ message.content| striptags('<img>') | raw}}
```

How can I display the message in the correct format?

Comment: `raw` filter should work fine. Make sure you clean twig cache after changing the template

Comment: "the <img> isn't considerated a tag" - what do you mean by that? Can you share the raw markup that is printed?

Comment: `<img onmouseover="alert('foo');" src="http://example.com/example.jpg">` will evade your `striptags`. It's not a safe function to use for escaping untrusted user input. See the red warning boxes on https://www.php.net/strip_tags.

Comment: "the <img> isn't considerated a tag" means that the `<img>` it is not converted to a image and it only prints something like `TestMessage<img alt="" class="emojioneemoji" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/emojione/assets/3.1/png/32/1f601.png"><img alt="" class="emojioneemoji src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/emojione/assets/3.1/png/32/1f601.png">`

Comment: Please share more details. If that is the markup from your response, this is a proper `img`  tag

Answer (score -1):

The `raw` filter should do it. As suggested by @u_mulder, if it doesn't work, maybe try clearing the cache.

```
{{ message.content | raw }}
```

However, you should never trust user input, so `striptags` to clear out any unexpected tags is recommended. I think in your example, the `striptags` filter should come after the `raw` filter. Before applying `raw` the variable should be escaped so `striptags` will most likely not strip anything.

```
{{ message.content | raw | striptags('<img>') }}
```

If `raw` doesn't work even after the cache has been cleared, maybe your variable has been escaped twice. Maybe trying dumping it to see what is the exact content of it.

EDIT:

As pointed out by @ceejayoz `strip_tags` is not safe and should not be used as a way to prevent XSS. So maybe you'll want to find a safer approach if you *"have"* to use `raw`.

Comment: `striptags` is not safe for untrusted input. Per https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/filters/striptags.html, "Internally, Twig uses the PHP strip_tags function.", and per https://www.php.net/strip_tags, **"This function should not be used to try to prevent XSS attacks."**

Comment: Right, but it still is better than nothing... no? I mean if he's going to use `raw` anyway...

Comment: OP might consider just storing them as UTF-8 emoji directly, or by converting them to something like Slack's `:emoji:` and processing those on output.